# JavaScript - Bring multiple variables from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following PHP code. It creates multiple variables using $a; for example: $numtoken1.

```
$sql ="SELECT token, dispositivo FROM dispositivos WHERE idcliente=1";
mysql_select_db('localiza');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($retval);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
    $numtoken['$a']=$row['token'];
    $numdispositivo['$a']=$row['dispositivo'];
    $a=$a++;
}
```

Using JavaScript, I want to call all the PHP variables using that code, but it only get the last `$a` number.

My question is: In a JavaScript loop, how can I dynamically insert the value for `$a`? Because in the above PHP, I have multiple values for `$a`.

```
var accessToken = "<?= $numtoken['$a']; ?>"a;
var deviceID = "<?= $numdispositivo['$a']; ?>";
```

Comment: remove the quotes from `['$a']`

Comment: your while loop keeps overwritting the data... do var_dump($numtoken) you will see... I think you'd want to remove the quotes from that $a inside the brakets

Comment: stop using mysql_ functions! they are deprecated!

Comment: k, but the problem is I have in php numtoken1,numtoken2,numtoken13... so I need if the javascript var accessToken = "<?= $numtoken['$a']; ?>"; insert automacally the $a value but that command "<?= $numtoken['$a']; ?>" is a php command, How can I change the $a in javascript and send it to php? –

Answer (score 2):

I suggest JSON:

```
    var accesstoken = JSON.parse("<?= json_encode($numtoken); ?>");
    var deviceID = JSON.parse("<?= json_encode($numdispositivo); ?>");
```

Comment: ok, but the problem is I have in php numtoken1,numtoken2,numtoken13... so I need if the javascript         var accessToken = "<?= $numtoken['$a']; ?>"; insert automacally the $a value but that command  "<?= $numtoken['$a']; ?>" is a php command, How can I change the $a in javascript and send it to php?

Comment: @RobertoBahia Using PHP to echo the JSON encoded sting into your javascript is a one way trick. If your issue is getting information from javascript back to PHP, you are going to need to look into making an AJAX call to a PHP processing script.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing I noticed when looking at this is that you are wrapping `$a` in single quotes (') instead of double quotes (") this means that instead of evaluating `$a` the key in the array will be the string "$a", so you'll be overwriting the value in each iteration of the `while` loop. See - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing for more info.

That being said the actual answer to your question varies, but the simplest method might be to use the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to convert your arrays into json objects.

```
var accessTokenArr = <?php print json_encode($numtoken); ?>
var deviceIdArr = <?php print json_encode($numdispositivo); ?>
```

Then you can iterate over the values in those arrays and do whatever you want to with the values. Fair warning - you may need to tweak that code a little as I haven't tested it to make sure it plays nicely.

Comment: So I bring hte information with that command:     var deviceIdArr = <?php print json_encode($numdispositivo); ?>;   I tried use subtr to get one value of array but is not possible. I tried too usinge var a = 0;     var deviceID1=deviceIdArr[a]; but can't get the value. you know how can I get the fvalues from json_encode?

Comment: It's difficult to say as I don't know what the structure of your data is. What errors are you getting in the console? You can also see what the data looks like by doing `console.log(accessTokenArr);` or `console.log(deviceIdArr);`